# My function returns same data without do the jobs

Tags: php

I have made function like below to remove html tags and special characters from the string.

```
function input_filter_data($data) {
        $data= trim($data);
        $data= stripslashes($data);
        $data= htmlspecialchars($data);
        $data= strip_tags($data);
        return $data;
}
```

and I am trying to use it like below

```
$affiliate_id =input_filter_data("Hello <b><i>world!</i></b>","<i>");

echo $affiliate_id;
```

But its giving me same result like

```
Hello <b><i>world!</i></b>","<i>
```

But if I use simple like

```
echo strip_tags("Hello <b><i>world!</i></b>","<i>");
```

then its removing all html tags from string.

I am not getting idea why its happening like this, let me know if anyone here can help me for solve the puzzle.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could help to debug what each step of `input_filter_data` does: after calling `htmlspecialchars`, the string does not contain any markup, but solely **escaped** markup. `strip_tags` won't perform any change on such a input

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir, so as per you, I should remove htmlspecialchars from function? sorry but I am not clear what to do. Thanks!

Comment: That depends on what you want to achieve - as you haven't written that in your question, it's difficult to advise how to resolve the problem. But maybe it could help to just swap the two lines (such that `strip_tags` is run before `htmlspecialchars`)